# Nativescript. Execution failed for task ':mergeF0DebugResources'

Tags: windows, nativescript

I am getting the following exception **Execution failed for task ':mergeF0DebugResources**.

When running 'tns build android' or 'tns run android --emulator'

tns version: 2.0.1
java version "1.8.0_92"

Comment: well...got the same error... have you solved it?

Comment: I installed android studio and follow the lower line steps, and it worked for me.

Comment: I had attested in service in a local 'c:/Project/my-app' and had worked. In my house had not worked, I found the house walks gave more than 240 characters that generated the error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error typically means your platform folder has been messed up.  Typically in v2.0x of NativeScript this is typically caused because you added or removed a plugin.   In the next (hopefully) version this should be fixed.

However, in the meantime to "fix" this error all you typically need to do is:

**tns platform remove android**

then

**tns platform add android**

The other possibility is that you do not have the android sdk installed properly.  If you type "android" at a command/terminal window, does it show that you have all the following installed:

- Android SDK Tools
- Android SDK Platform Tools
- Android SDK Build Tools
- At least one of the SDK's, 4.4.2 and higher
- Android Support Repository
- Android Support Library

All of them must be showing that they are installed.